# Do we really need interfaces for multiple inheritance in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-inheritance

As I was learning about interfaces I came across the fact that they can be used to implement Multiple Interface Inheritance and that Multiple Class Inheritance is not possible in C#. So, I found the following code which implements multiple interface inheritance.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    interface IB
    {
        void PrintB();
    }

    class A
    {
        public void PrintA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrintA() Method.");
        }
    }

    class B : IB
    {
        public void PrintB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrintB() Method.");
        }
    }

    class C : A, IB
    {
        B bObject = new B();

        public void PrintB()
        {
            bObject.PrintB();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            C cObject = new C();
            cObject.PrintA();
            cObject.PrintB();
        }
    }
}
```

But in this code we are inheriting Class A directly. But for inheriting the method of Class B we are using interface IB.

Now, I can't see the advantage of doing so. We could write this code without using interface IB like this.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class A
    {
        public void PrintA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrintA() Method.");
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        public void PrintB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrintB() Method.");
        }
    }

    class C : A
    {
        B bObject = new B();

        public void PrintB()
        {
            bObject.PrintB();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            C cObject = new C();
            cObject.PrintA();
            cObject.PrintB();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, why did we used interface in the first place, if we could write it without the interface?

Does this mean multiple inheritance can be done without using interfaces?

Or multiple inheritance cannot be done even using interfaces?

Comment: Your proposed alternative isn't the same thing though.  C no longer itself implements any other types.  It *contains properties* which are other types.  So what exactly are you asking?  Why interfaces exist when you personally would rather not use them?  You've written a contrived example that doesn't mean anything, and replaced it with another contrived example that doesn't mean anything.  But this doesn't demonstrate anything about interfaces.  If you're asking why interfaces exist, I imagine there's quite a bit of writing on the subject.

Comment: What if you want to have method `PrintB` in class `C` without `B bObject = new B();` in it?

Comment: @David can you give me a simple example of multiple interface inheritance if my example is wrong.

Comment: @Learner: What if you want an object which is both `IComparable` (because it can be meaningfully compared with like objects using custom business rules) and `IEnumerable` (because it can be enumerated)?  Or any other two or more interfaces, whether they're built-in to the framework or custom to your business objects?  How would you accomplish that without interfaces?

Comment: Its like a game of chess. You can learn how the pieces move by reading about it, but you really don't understand how you can *use* them unless you practice. This is not a question that can be answered in Q & A format. But one way to learn how useful interfaces are is by reading the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition). Of course, that is just one way to use interfaces, they have been useful long before DI came about.

Comment: But I would have to implement both interfaces. Then why would I inherit from Interfaces? I can just write a  CompareTo() method without using Interface and same with the GetEnumerator() method?

Comment: @Learner: `"But I would have to implement both interfaces."` Yes, that's exactly what we're talking about. Multiple interfaces. `"Then why would I inherit from Interfaces?"` So your object can be of those types. You seem to be missing something about static typing. Just because you write a class that has a method called `CompareTo()` doesn't mean it's an instance of `IComparable`.  You can't use it in any context that requires an `IComparable` without implementing the interface. The compiler isn't terribly concerned with the names of your methods, it's concerned with the types of your objects.

Comment: @Learner: `"Then why would I inherit from Interfaces?"` - Note, terminology is important.  You don't *inherit from* interfaces.  You *implement* interfaces.  Inheritance and polymorphism are two different things.

Comment: So then that means only benefit of having interface would be that we can deal with a class in respect of the interfaces it implements.

Comment: And that also means that multiple interface inheritance is not really multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Learner: It's multi-type polymorphism, not really "multiple inheritance".  The latter is a kind of the former, but the former is not a kind of the latter.  (Which itself is a metaphor for polymorphism, I suppose.)

Comment: @David Thanks for helping me. But can you tell me about multi-type polymorphism or a good article, video or anything on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a point about virtual methods. We want to be able to do this:

```
interface IPrint
{
    void Print();
}

class A : IPrint
{
    public void Print()
    {
    }
}

class B : IPrint
{
    public void Print()
    {
    }
}
...
foreach (IPrint p in printables)
{
    p.Print();
}
```

Your approach cannot do that, because your PrintB in class C is just a method. Inheritance is not about having methods with the same name, but about defining verbs that perform an action on the instance of the class they are designed for.

Comment: Same thing can be done by defining a Print Class which both A and B inherit

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Inheritance leads to the [Diamond Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). And that Diamond is a Programmers worst enemy.

So the designers of .NET or the CLI (I can never remember wich) decided they are were not going to deal with that, and mandated "single Inheritance only". Wich is one of the common strategies to deal with that "Diamond of Death".

As only allowing single Inheritance meant somet things would be missing, they Implemented Interfaces to offset it. It is one of the many ways in wich .NET is more restrictive then say Native C++ and had to invent a replacement for something trivial. But in the long run it prooved to be slightly better doing it this way.

Comment: I think you meant *CLR*, not CLI.

Comment: I just looked those up again and CLR was part of the .NET Implementation of a CLI. So I am honestly not sure in wich part here the limit applied too. I do remember that some parts of the whole thing did have Multiple Inheritance support. But someone along the development chain decided to just dodge teh Diamond Problem and now we are stuck in single Inheritance.